# Why can I not declare multiple methods on my MVC Controller?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to create a web API using .Net Core MVC.  If I only declare one method on the controller, I can call the API using HttpClient from another application.  However, if I add a second public method to the controller, the HttpClient call always returns status code 500, no matter which method I call, and I cannot find any errors coming from the server.  What am I missing that will allow me to declare multiple methods from the same controller?

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {                  
        public async Task<ResponseInfoList> Method1([FromBody]RequestInfoList value)
        {
            return new ResponseInfoList() {};
        }

        public async Task<ResponseInfoList> Method2([FromBody]RequestInfoList value)
        {
            return new ResponseInfoList() { };
        }
    }
```

Comment: Two things to check here: 1.) your routing config. 2.) user F12 tools (network activity) to see messages going to/from your server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the help @Igor.  It looks like they removed RoutePrefix in MVC 6.  This is what I ended up with.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{            
    [Route("Method1")]
    public async Task<ResponseInfoList> Method1([FromBody]RequestInfoList value)
    {
        return new ResponseInfoList() {};
    }
    [Route("Method2")]
    public async Task<ResponseInfoList> Method2([FromBody]RequestInfoList value)
    {
        return new ResponseInfoList() { };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Route` should be `RoutePrefix`

You can then either

- use `Route` on each action/method as seen below.  With the out of the box routing config the value you had defined above is not even necessary as it is configured to go to `api/[controller]` by default.
- Alternatively you can specify the `action` as a part of the global routing configuration and use a placeholder. By default there is no action placeholder and the routing is done based on the Http Verb (get,put,delete,post)

Code with `RoutePrefix` and `Route` attributes

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Values")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{            
    [Route("Method1")]
    public async Task<ResponseInfoList> Method1([FromBody]RequestInfoList value)
    {
        return new ResponseInfoList() {};
    }
    [Route("Method2")]
    public async Task<ResponseInfoList> Method2([FromBody]RequestInfoList value)
    {
        return new ResponseInfoList() { };
    }
}
```

Comment: Is RoutePrefix part of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc?  I don't see that one, though it does have Route.  Am I just missing something, or is the syntax different for Core? Thank you.

Comment: @Eric - you did not tag `core` in your question but `asp.net-mvc` so this answer is based on that (mvc 5, webapi 2).

Comment: @Eric - I did reread your question and saw you mentioned it at the top. I fixed the tags for you in the question though so it is clear to others.